# Query to group these rows by date and user, starting a new group after specific event

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

A call center has customers exceeding their line capacity, and has some customers hitting the busy signal as a result. Some customers will call over and over until they get through, and other customers will give up after a certain number of attempts.

We have a CSV file exported from the phone switching software with records like this (heavily simplified) example:

```
TIME    NUMBER    RESULT
10:00   8675309   Busy signal
10:00   5551234   Busy signal
10:01   8675309   Busy signal
10:02   8675309   Answered
11:00   5551234   Answered
12:00   8675309   Busy signal
12:01   8675309   Busy signal
12:02   8675309   Busy signal
13:00   8675309   Busy signal
```

I'm looking to generate a query in an Excel file (using PowerQuery) that will output something like this:

```
NUMBER    ATTEMPT START   ATTEMPT END   NUM. CALLS   STATUS
5551234   10:00           11:00         2            Answered
8675309   10:00           10:02         3            Answered
8675309   12:00           13:00         4            Busy Signal
```

Here's the logic I'm trying to use:

- If no calls were answered, all calls on a single day are grouped under one attempt, with status Busy Signal.
- If a call was answered, that marks the end of an attempt. The attempt ended in this way will have status Answered. Future calls by the same number will start a new attempt.
- The start of an attempt is the time of the first call
- The end of an attempt is either the time of the call that was answered, or the last call made by that number that day

I'm stuck on how to divide up the two attempts from [Jenny](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WTdTwcmxyo). It's fairly easy to write a query that will group all calls by one number into one attempt, but that would tell a misleading story. For example, in this case it would say she had one attempt starting at 10:00 and ending at 13:00, with a total of 7 calls. Whether it labeled that as "answered" or "busy signal" status, either would be misleading.

Comment: You say "If a call was answered, that marks the end of an attempt. Future calls by the same number will count as a new attempt. This attempt will have status Answered"  but after 8675309 is answered, your suggested solution for their future call has status "Busy Signal" not "Answered"

Comment: @horseyride - Thank you for the feedback! I clarified the logic to be accurate to what I was trying to say; the sentence order was very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might involve something like:

1. Group your initial table (from the CSV) by `NUMBER` so that you get a "NUMBER table" per number.
2. Take each "NUMBER table" (from the previous step) and split it further into a list of sub-tables, where each sub-table represents an "attempt".

   - My understanding is that achieving this splitting behaviour is a bit awkward since I don't believe there's a built-in function in M which allows you to split a table based on the occurrence(s) of a given value.
   - But there are functions which let you find the positions of a certain value (in your case "Answered") in a table -- and there are also functions which let you "slice" a table, if you give them a starting position and the number of rows you want.
   - Using these functions in conjunction with one another should allow you to split the "NUMBER table" into a list of "attempt tables". In other words, all the attempts for a given number.
3. Take each "attempt table" (from the previous step) and summarise when the attempt started, when it ended, how many calls were made, its final status.
4. After all of this, for each `NUMBER` you should have a list of attempts which, within the context of the outermost table, you can flatten and end up with a table that looks something like:

[image: Output]

(The order of the rows is different, but each row in and of itself is correct I think.)

---

The code below tries to achieve the above:

```
let
    initialTable = Table.FromRows({
        {"10:00", "8675309", "Busy signal"},
        {"10:00", "5551234", "Busy signal"},
        {"10:01", "8675309", "Busy signal"},
        {"10:02", "8675309", "Answered"},
        {"11:00", "5551234", "Answered"},
        {"12:00", "8675309", "Busy signal"},
        {"12:01", "8675309", "Busy signal"},
        {"12:02", "8675309", "Busy signal"},
        {"13:00", "8675309", "Busy signal"}
    }, type table [TIME = text, NUMBER = text, RESULT = text]),
    indexColumn = Table.AddIndexColumn(initialTable, "_index", 0), // Remove if you have no need for it. But can be useful if you need to later sort by the CSV's original row order.
    grouped = Table.Group(indexColumn, "NUMBER", {"toCombine", (tableForSomeNumber as table) as any =>
        let
            // Split table into a list of sub-tables, where each sub-table represents an "attempt".
            listOfAttemptTables = 
                let
                    // If you find original row order isn't preserved, sort here and, where applicable, have all subsequent expressions refer to the sorted table instead of "tableForSomeNumber".
                    positionOfLastRow = Table.RowCount(tableForSomeNumber) - 1,
                    answeredPositions = Table.PositionOf(tableForSomeNumber, [RESULT = "Answered"], Occurrence.All, each [RESULT]),
                    endPositions  = if List.Contains(answeredPositions, positionOfLastRow) then answeredPositions else answeredPositions & {positionOfLastRow},
                    startPositions = {0} & List.Transform(List.RemoveLastN(endPositions, 1), each _ + 1),
                    zipped = List.Zip({startPositions, endPositions}),
                    split = List.Transform(zipped, each Table.Range(tableForSomeNumber, _{0}, _{1} - _{0} + 1))
                in split,

            // Summarise each "attempt".
            summarised = List.Transform(listOfAttemptTables, (attemptTable as table) as record =>
                let
                    // If you find original row order isn't preserved, sort here and, where applicable, have all subsequent expressions refer to the sorted table instead of "attemptTable".
                    // Also, if you find that you want to retain the original row order when expanding the summaries (later on), include the first row's _index value in the record, include _index when expanding, then sort by the _index. That might be one way to do that. 
                    lastRow = Table.Last(attemptTable),
                    summary = [
                        NUMBER = lastRow[NUMBER],
                        ATTEMPT START = Table.First(attemptTable)[TIME],
                        ATTEMPT END = lastRow[TIME],
                        NUMBER OF CALLS = Table.RowCount(attemptTable),
                        STATUS = lastRow[RESULT]
                    ]
                in summary
            ),

            // Turn into a table of "attempts" (within the context of the current NUMBER)
            toTable = Table.FromRecords(summarised, type table [NUMBER = text, ATTEMPT START = text, ATTEMPT END = text, NUMBER OF CALLS = Int64.Type, STATUS = text])
        in toTable
    , type list}),
    combined = Table.Combine(grouped[toCombine])
in
    combined
```

- Something to note is that this code assumes (and requires) that the data at each stage is sorted chronologically. Having unsorted data when splitting the tables into "attempts" and when summarising the attempts will give incorrect/nonsensical output at the end.
- I haven't done any sorting in the code, as I was getting expected output without sorting, but I don't know if your real CSV is sorted or if the functions I've used are guaranteed to preserve row order. I've left comments in the code where the data must be sorted before proceeding and you can just use `Table.Sort` when and where required.